# How to proceed after finding three Christoffel symbols?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, metric-tensor

> I have a two dimensional metric: 
>   $$(ds)^2=\frac{(dx)^2-(cdt)^2}{t^2}.$$
>   The question requires one two find all non-zero Christoffel symbols.

This I think I have managed to do as follows:

we have the elements of the metric tensor given by:

$g_{11}=\frac{1}{t^2} $ , $g_{22}=-\frac{c^2}{t^2}$ , $g^{11}=t^2 $ 
 and  $g^{22}=\frac{-t^2}{c^2}$

To get :

$g^{11}[11,1]=\frac{1}{2}g^{11}[g_{11},1]=\frac{1}{2}t^2\frac{\partial (\frac{1}{t^2})}{\partial x}=0$

$g^{11}[12,1]=\frac{1}{2}g^{11}[g_{11},2]=\frac{1}{2}t^2\frac{\partial (\frac{1}{t^2})}{\partial t}=\Big(\frac{-t^2}{2}\Big)\Big(\frac{2}{t}\Big)=-t$

$g^{11}[22,1]=-\frac{1}{2}g^{11}[g_{22},1]=-\frac{1}{2}t^2\frac{\partial (\frac{-c^2}{t^2})}{\partial x}=0$

$g^{22}[11,2]=-\frac{1}{2}g^{22}[g_{11},2]=-\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{-t^2}{c^2}\Big)\frac{\partial (\frac{1}{t^2})}{\partial x}=\Big( -\frac{t^2}{c^2} \Big)\Big(\frac {-2}{t}\Big)=\frac{2t}{c^2}$

$g^{22}[12,2]=\frac{1}{2}g^{22}[g_{22},1]=-\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{-t^2}{c^2}\Big)\frac{\partial (\frac{-c^2}{t^2})}{\partial x}=0$

$g^{22}[22,2]=\frac{1}{2}g^{22}[g_{22},2]=\frac{1}{2}\Big(\frac{-t^2}{c^2}\Big)\frac{\partial (\frac{-c^2}{t^2})}{\partial t}=\Big(\frac{-t^2}{2c^2}\Big)\Big(\frac{2c^2}{t}\Big)=-t$

Now, my trouble is how to find the geodesics $x(t)$ and ${\bf sketching \ its \ graph}$

I said :

For the geodesics we have :

$\frac{d^2x}{ds^2} + \Big\{ \underset{1 2}{ 1}\Big\}\frac{dx}{ds}\frac{dt}{ds}=0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{d^2x}{ds^2} -t\frac{dx}{ds}\frac{dt}{ds}=0$

and also:

$\frac{d^2t}{ds^2} + \Big\{ \underset{1 1}{ 2}\Big\}\frac{dx}{ds}\frac{dt}{ds}=0$

$\Rightarrow \frac{d^2t}{ds^2} -\Big( \frac{2t}{c^2}\Big)\frac{dx}{ds}\frac{dx}{ds}=0$

So what happens with the the third Christoffel symbol, $t$ in this case, since I have two equations? This is where I do not get, and also on the sketch part, I think that maybe if we get the solution, then we will see the kind of curve it gives?

*How do we formulate the geodesic equations given more than two Christoffel symbols?* I know how to if I have two symbols, one for $g^{11}$ and another for $g^{22}$ . In this case I have three.

Comment: Your value of $g_{22}$ is missing a minus sign. Also, I'm not really sure what you're asking about the Christoffel symbols. Could you please edit the question, specifying where exactly the problem lies?

Comment: No ALL_CAPS please!! Use more elegant formatting like italics or bold. I'll fix it up here, but please don't do it; it's very very annoying. Also, there's no need to include edit tables: anyone interested can easily view the edit history through https://physics.stackexchange.com/posts/424010/revisions

Answer (score 2):

The geodesic equation is 
$$
\frac{d^2x^\mu}{d\tau^2}+ \sum_{\alpha\beta}\Gamma^\mu_{\alpha\beta}\frac{d x^\alpha}{d\tau }\frac{d x^\beta}{d\tau}=0.
$$
The sum on $\alpha,\beta$ means  you have as many equations as the range of the index $\mu$, not as many as there are non=zero $\Gamma$'s. In your case there only ever 2 equations.

In the Euclidean signature verion, your metric is that of Hyperbolic  (Lobachevski) space in the Poincare upper half-plane realization. In this  case the geodesics are circles with centers on the $x$ axis. They presumably become hyperbolas of some sort for the Lozenzian signature.